# Why is this static_cast not allowed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, static-cast

I have an object of class A that I want to allocate on a custom stack object.  To do this, I simply move the stack pointer as many bytes as the object is in size and return its previous value:

```
class A : public B {}; //B is from a precompiled library

class stack {
public:
    stack(void): _top(&_storage[0]) {}

    template <typename T>
    inline T* push(void) {
        T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(_top);

        _top += sizeof(T);

        return ptr;
    }

    //...

private:
    char _storage[1024];
    char* _top;
};

stack _stack;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A* a = _stack.push<A>(); //ignore the lack of a constructor call

    return 0;
}
```

Visual C++ simply tells me that static_cast cannot convert from char* to A*.  A regular C style cast does not give me this error, but I'd rather be more explicit and avoid a dynamic cast (A inherits from another class, but does not contribute to the vtable it doesn't have).  Is there any difference between the two in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By design.

The `static_cast` conversion is not designed to convert between unrelated pointer types, for that you need to use `reinterpret_cast`. If you want to be explicit about the cast you are doing, then use the correct one. The C style cast will do a `reinterpret_cast` in this case.

You really need to research about the different cast operators, as the comment on `dynamic_cast` does not make much sense either.

Comment: I thought I understood that dynamic_cast changes the dynamic type of an object, is that not correct?

Comment: @NmdMystery: Nothing changes the *dynamic type* of an object. An object is of a type when it is constructed and the type never changes (references or pointers may have a different type, as in a base, but the object is always of the same type). Again, the best you can do is to reach for a book or tutorial and clear up your doubts.

Comment: Well it was an honest mistake, I thought I already had a pretty good idea of what each cast did.  Guess not.

Comment: @NmdMystery: No worries. If it had been deemed anything other than a honest mistake there probably would be a few votes to close.

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, the solution is to use `reinterpret_cast`, which is meant to be used when casting between unrelated pointer types:

```
T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(_top);
```

If you use `placement new` instead, you not only avoid the casting problem but you also fix the problem of not calling the constructor for types that have a constructor:

```
T* ptr = new(_top) T();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit or explicit conversion from char* to A*.  You want reinterpret_cast<> to perform this type of cast.

For more detail, see [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)